# php arrray groups by multiple sets

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have data in set of groups 
each group contains 3 Values As name , mobile , message.

How to store these multiple values in array and get echo of separate group .??

```
<?php
$full_name = array( );

$full_name["name"] = "john1";
$full_name["mobile"] = "923456812536";
$full_name["message"] = "message1";

$full_name["name"] = "john2";
$full_name["mobile"] = "565656565656";
$full_name["message"] = "message2";

$full_name["name"] = "john3";
$full_name["mobile"] = "444442222222222";
$full_name["message"] = "message3";

$full_name["name"] = "john4";
$full_name["mobile"] = "2222";
$full_name["message"] = "2222222222";

echo $full_name["name"]."</br>".
     $full_name["mobile"]."</br>".
     $full_name["message"]."</br></br>"

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your inserts into the array like:

```
$full_name[] = array(
    "name" => "john1",
    "mobile" => "923456812536",
    "message" => "message1",
);
```

etc

to give yourself a multi-dimensional array

then loop using

```
foreach($full_name as $name) {
    echo $name['name'], ' ', $name['mobile'], ' ', $name['message'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use multi dimensional arrays like this

```
$full_name["name"][0] = "john1";
$full_name["mobile"][0] = "923456812536";
$full_name["message"][0] = "message1";

$full_name["name"][1] = "john2";
$full_name["mobile"][1] = "565656565656";
$full_name["message"][1] = "message2";
```

And echo a group like this

```
echo implode(", ", $full_name["name"]);
```

However, you need to make sure that `["name"][x]` corresponds with `["mobile"][x]` as these sub arrays are independent of each other. If you use Mark Baker's answer, you know that `[x]["name"]` belongs to the same person as `[x]["mobile"]`

Comment: i dont know the exact values of data . therefore i can not use 
[0]
[1]

Because dont know the total Group sets

Comment: @myeishvar Well you can use `[]` (as Rizier123 suggested). With the information given, it is difficult to help you further than this

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you: With the `[]` it's going to insert the data into the next field of the array

```
<?php 
    $full_name = array( );

    $full_name["name"][] = "john1";
    $full_name["mobile"][] = "923456812536";
    $full_name["message"][] = "message1";

    $full_name["name"][] = "john2";
    $full_name["mobile"][] = "565656565656";
    $full_name["message"][] = "message2";

    $full_name["name"][] = "john3";
    $full_name["mobile"][] = "444442222222222";
    $full_name["message"][] = "message3";

    $full_name["name"][] = "john4";
    $full_name["mobile"][] = "2222";
    $full_name["message"][] = "2222222222";

    print_r($full_name["name"]);
    echo "</br>";
    print_r($full_name["mobile"]);
    echo "</br>";
    print_r($full_name["message"]);
?>
```